# Get Difference Between Responses Constantly Updating

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get the difference of a HTTP response that is constantly updating. The response looks like this:

```
  "values": [
    {
      "value": "value1",
    },
    {
      "value": "value2",
    },
```

With 100's of rows. The "value" always stays the same but the "value1" or "value2" could change.

Then in the 2nd requests response looks like this:

```
  "values": [
    {
      "value": "value1_changed",
    },
    {
      "value": "value2",
    },
```

The 1st value changes. How could i get it to tell me the value that changes every request it sends?

Comment: can you show us exactly the input ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this, depending on how your data is processed.

```
import json

# Base data
current = json.dumps({'values': [{'value': 'value1',},{'value': 'value2',}]})
current = json.loads(current)

# Run until you want it to stop on a given condition.
while True:
    # Read data
    new_read = json.dumps({'values': [{'value': 'value1_changed',},{'value': 'value2',}]})
    new_read = json.loads(new_read)

    # Check if data exists
    if new_read:
        # Run through each key

        for key in new_read.keys():
            # set interim variable for the new list
            v_new = new_read[key]

            # Check if key exits in the current data
            if current[key]:
                # Create temp variable for current data
                v_current = current[key]

                # For each element in the new data list
                for dd in v_new:
                    # For each element in the current data list
                    for cc in v_current:

                        # List comprehension to compare values
                        res = [v for k, v in dd.items() if cc[k] != v]

                    # If we get a result, print all results
                    if len(res) > 0:
                        print("\n".join(res))

            # If the current data doesn't have the key, print hte key
            else:
                print(key)


    # Set current to new_read
    current = new_read

    # Break on False clause
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

using a memory inefficient list comprehension, my first attempt to return the changed values in the key "values" of the dictionary would look something like this:

```
changed_values = [current_dict["values"][i]["values"] for i in range(len(current_dict)) if current_dict["values"][i]["values"] != previous_dict["values"][i]["values"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear that I understand, you've got a list of dictionaries that you receive through the HTTP request.

What you want to know is **which** dictionaries are changed, or which key-values of the dictionaries have been changed?

I'll try to answer both.

I'll assume that the request will always return the dictionaries in the same order if not, you might want to sort them based on some criteria, making the "identification" of the dictionaries easier, so you know which dictionary you're comparing with which dictionary.

You can check which **dictionary** changed by iterating through the values and just comparing the old dictionary with the new one. It will always tell you if it is changed or not. Example here:

```
old_values = [ { "1": 1 }, { "2": 2 }, ..., { "n": n } ]
new_values = [ { "1": 2 }, { "2": 2 }, ..., { "n": n } ] # only "1" changed

for iterator in range(len(old_values)): # we'll also assume that the lengths of the responses are the same if not, you're to make the check here
     if old_values[iterator] != new_values[iterator]:
          print("Change detected at: " + str(old_values[iterator]))
```

If you want to check **which** value inside the dictionaries changed, then you can also go through the dictionaries too the following way (same variables as above):

```
for iterator in range(len(old_values)):
     for values in old_values[iterator]:
          if old_values[iterator][values] != new_values[iterator][values]:
               print("Change detected at: " + str(old_values[iterator][values]))
```

Comment: Ive tested this and it works, but when i use my response which is: 
```{"values": [{"value1": 'value1_value', "value2": "value2_value"}, {"value1": 'value1_value', "value2": "value2_value"}, ]}```
It does not work.